# What's the minimum vent diameter required for my drain line?

Tags: drain-waste-vent

I'm adding a secondary bar sink in a kitchen area, which will extend the waste pipe to it's farthest length, so I need to put in a waste drain vent pipe up the wall and through the roof.

The drain pipe is 1-1/2" diameter and I'm wondering if the vent pipe going up the wall can be a smaller diameter, like 1" or 3/4", so I don't need to cut such a wide channel in the drywall and fight with fiberglass insulation.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this:

> Vent piping should never be less than half the diameter of the fixture
>   drain it serves, and usually should be closer in size. For example,
>   waste pipes of 3" and 4" diameters should be serviced by a minimum 2"
>   vent pipe. And regardless of piping size, no vent should be smaller
>   than 1 1/4" pipe. Dual vents which are to service more than one
>   fixture should be slightly larger than required for a single fixture.

source: [plumbing-basics.com](http://www.plumbing-basics.com/drainage/vent-piping.htm)